# Different domain extension for blog

Tags: seo, domains, blog, top-level-domains

I have a main website under a `.be` extension as it is mainly aiming at the Belgian market.
Now I want to start a separate blog with topics that are related to my .be-website.

I currently also own the `.com` domain and think about putting the blog there.

So website would be like `example.be`  and blog would be under `example.com`

Can that create any problems for ranking, etc. ?

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is creating and storing content in a subfolder of the domain you want to increase ranking and visibility. However, if you already have content under something such as a subdomain, it's strongly recommended that you do not move it (unless there's not too much content yet).

You can use hreflang tags and international targeting configurations in Webmaster Tools to assist with your .be efforts. I'm not an expert on international targeting as I don't do much myself, but this may provide some insight.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6059209

Answer (score 0):

no problem. Google is pretty good to pinpoint right visitors recognizing the language of the site.

Comment: Do you have any evidence or resources to support your statement? What does the original question have to do with language? Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations.

Comment: @AndrewLott, i thought till now, project managers in webdev usually know, what has a country code TLD to do with its country language. Further they usually know, that ccTLDs are treated by Google as generic domains. Vice versa treatments are based on the content language of the domain's site. So G treats .com-site according to its content language. If .be-site is in french, so its served to belgians based on ip, and to french speakers, based on their browser language. The .com-site is treated exactly on the same way. The question was only about .com-based problems for belgian content.

Comment: Yes, but that's secondary to the question of whether the company blog should go on a separate domain in the first place. I don't think the language really has anything to do with that as Google doesn't care as much about the Generic TLD as long as hreflang tags are set correctly, for which your answer doesn't provide any detail.